# keep linked div behind normal div

Tags: html, css

I want to keep a div on another div, which is linked to any site.

here is my css

```
.link_div a {
    float:left;
    width:80px;
    height:20px;
    background:yellow;
}
.over {
    position:absolute;
    left:0;
    top:0;
    background:red;
    width:80px;
    height:20px;
}
```

here is html

```
<div class="link_div"> <a href="#">HELLO</a> </div>
<div class="over"></div>
```

Is this possible to keep "Over" div on top and link should be on ?

Comment: Something like this?
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3680429/click-through-a-div-to-underlying-elements

Comment: What do you want here? The title suggests an order, but in your question you talk about being _on top_. Is `z-index`what you want or is it really the positioning on the screen?

Comment: @Smamatti I want keep div on top like we do in z-index. here problem is that Link is not working in this condition. I want Div on top of linked div and link should work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is an awesome post:
[Click through a DIV to underlying elements](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3680429/click-through-a-div-to-underlying-elements/4839672#4839672)

Adding this css to your `.over` should do it:

```
pointer-events:none;
```

plus for IE:

```
filter:progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.AlphaImageLoader(src='your_transparent.png', sizingMethod='scale');
background:none !important;
```

You could get something like this then:
http://www.searchlawrence.com/click-through-a-div-to-underlying-elements.html

All credits go to [this guy's post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3680429/click-through-a-div-to-underlying-elements/4839672#4839672) of course.

Comment: Awesome! Thanks for sharing this. I didn't know clicking-through works at all.

Comment: @Mathieu thanks but  http://www.searchlawrence.com/click-through-a-div-to-underlying-elements.html
  is not working in IEs